# How can I watch 3DS Nintendo Video from another country?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, networking

I have an American 3DS, but I now live in Germany.  The stupid media-licensing pillowfights are ruining my day, again.

I just found out a bunch of great content is coming to Nintendo Video, and as far as I can tell there's no way for me to view it. When I try to download videos, it tells me they're "not available in this region", even though if I had a *German* 3DS I'd have no problem.

I know the 3DS has some kind of "proxy" settings in the wireless config, but I haven't been able to get it working.  I've tried open proxies from this list somebody linked to from a forum, and I have a SOCKS5 proxy running on my computer (executive summary: `ssh -D8080 me@server-in-the.us`) through which I've successfully watched a ton of Hulu and Netflix on the PC, but which I've never been able to figure out how to use with gaming consoles.

Has anybody gotten this to actually work?  Can you lay out in detail exactly what you did to get there?  Alternately, is there anywhere online (shady is OK by me, I *tried* to do it the legit way) where I can watch this content?

Comment: It may be possible for you to go ahead and reroute your internet connections and set them to your German one. This may work or it might not. However, you could try this and see if it works or not.

Comment: I have recently moved to Japan and have the same problem. Damned region locking and the likes should be considered an act of terrorism. O.K. I am over reacting but I have never met someone that is happy with region locking or the like.

Comment: @rom016, you might have met someone who is happy with it -- "content executives" that manage the videos you're trying to watch.  You'd know them by the little horns on top of their heads :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this will work but if you mess with your router/network you might could redirect the IP address from your router to an American IP(creating your own vpn or using IP address forwarding to redirect the traffic).  Similar things like this have been done to play games online form consoles that only support Lan games to get them to work over an internet connection.  Such things can't be done directly from the console and require a PC to do.

Comment: When I mentioned running a SOCKS5 proxy on my computer, this is the kind of thing I was talking about.  The one idea for "redirecting... to an American IP" didn't work.  If you have a specific setup that *does* work, by all means please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I'll do these in steps.

1. Touch the System Settings icon on your Home Screen.
2. Touch the "Other Settings" button.
3. Touch "Profile."
4. Press "Region Settings."
5. Change your Region.

I don't know if this will fix it, but have a go.

Comment: This would be the correct answer if I'd moved to another country where my "version" (?) of the 3DS is sold.  There are a lot of countries listed, but they're all in the Americas.  My current country (Germany) is not listed :(

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use a Proxy on a 3DS, try setting it up as a wi-fi hotspot. Look up VPN or Proxy hotspot on google.

Answer (score -1):

Get a VPN account in the US. Set your router to connect to it. Connect DS to router. This will require knowledge of how to setup VPN connections on your router. Something further, most SOHO routers do not allow VPN tunnels from them, only through them Probably will need to get a business class product (Cisco/Juniper, etc).

Comment: There is a reason these Videos are not available at this certain location. Recommending an illegal method is not something we should be explaining too other users on how todo it.

Comment: @Hound VPNs are illegal? I didn't realize they were since most routers have a special tab to input your VPNS

Comment: Depending on the country you're in they may be illegal. VPNs are legal in Germany, but breaching copyright is not. So it should be fine if he uses a proxy.

Comment: I'm pretty sure nobody has made circumventing geo-blocking with a VPN *illegal* yet -- it's not a copyright violation, at the very least.  At worst, you might have "agreed" (via click-wrap agreement) not to access some content from specific physical locations, but such a contract is absolutely unenforceable.

Answer (score -1):

I think the country of where it's sent to is saved in the version so i don't think it's possible without like completely messing with it